# (Maven+Eclipse)How each developer handle the jars locally?

Tags: eclipse, maven

I'm kinda newbie to Maven and Continuous Integration, so excuse my trivial questions below
In our project we intend to introduce the Continuous Integration through performing automated daily builds on our development integration server using Maven and hudson

on our projects we used to check-in the all the jars (internal, commercial & 3rd party) to SCM under one separate project and force the web project to depend on that project so that the project can compile in eclipse then exporting an EAR

my question is, how will each developer locally on his machine compile the project now ?, should we remove the jars project at all from scm ?
If yes : does this mean that each developer must refer to the enterprise's maven repository from within eclipse so that the project can compile ? and in that case there will be extreme NW overhead ??
If No : there might be a conflict between jars on scm and those in maven repository

another question that is related to the above one, will each developer have his own maven local repository on his machine ?
final question, shall each developer compile the code using maven (through M2Eclipse) or using eclipse compiler as normal ?

thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way we do, and I believe is quite common, is

- We have our own installation of a repository manager, for example [Nexus](http://nexus.sonatype.org/), installed at some machine in the intranet, available for all developers to use
- Jars would not be in the SCM, but stored in the Nexus or equivalent. Common arrangement is to have there one repo for external dependencies, one for internal snapshot builds and one for internal release builds (per project). We have defined maven central repository as well as the internal repositories in Maven configuration, storing the artifacts in the relevant internal repositories (external, internal-release or internal-snapshot) and picking them up from there, but having central repo as a backup for standard plugins.
- Repository references (definitions, urls) are either in Maven settings file or then in the pom.xml. Individual developer should not need to do anything, he/she just uses these files. pom.xml would be in the SCM, settings file could be there or not.
- Maven uses also local cache when it downloads the files, so they are downloaded only once per version/machine, which should keep the NW overhead tolerable. Intranet repo is there also partly to reduce external network overhead.
- [Maven release plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-release-plugin/) is often used to handle internal-snapshot and internal-release repository updates
- Each developer has a local repository cache in his machine. This is a standard Maven feature. Eclipse can refer to these same files.
- Code can be compiled with the help of eclipse-maven plugin (of which M2E is the most common), using Maven on the command line or then using Maven to generate regular Eclipse project files and then normally with Eclipse. We use command line and M2E+Eclipse both for this.
- SCM would be for source code, repositories for binaries (including .jars)

Comment: Thanks that helped, but few more questions
(1) Is Nexus Open Source enough or this needs the commercial one ?
(2) Didn't get why you use command line and M2Eclipse both ? I tried creating maven project from within eclipse using M2Eclipse only. also is it good practice to get eclipse and maven use same "target" folder for the build ?
(3) As we will use multi-module but in flat structure in order not to confuse the developers also as this is the default for eclipse , but I heard that Release plugin won't work that way, so what's your experience on this ?

Comment: Sorry, butting in, but for (3) the answer is, yes that's right but the release plugin is almost more trouble than it's worth anyway (search for blog posts about it).

Comment: 1) It depends on your needs. See the differences [here](http://www.sonatype.com/books/nexus-book/reference/intro-sect-choosing.html). Also, Nexus is only one of the options, here's a [comparison between Nexus and Artifactory](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/johnsmart/archive/2010/01/03/tale-two-repository-managers-nexus-and-artifactory-compared-and-co), for example. 3) I didn't really follow what is the flat structure here. Maybe you should elaborate on that. That might be a topic for a new SO question, not a comment.

Comment: 2) Sometimes it's more convenient to use command line, sometimes eclipse. Eclipse is a bit slow, and if you are only changing something small, it's more efficient to build + run unit tests + run integration tests on the command line instead of firing up the Eclipse IDE to do that. Also, build automation would use it on command line anyway. For general development, using IDE is usually the choice.

Answer (score 2):

You configure all dependencies in the pom.xml for each project. Maven then downloads all needed jars from your enterprise repository. You don't need your SCM project any more and i would remove it.
I don't think there is much network overhead, because Maven only downloads the jars the first time they are needed. After that, they are in the local repository (which every developer has on his machine), and only updates will be downloaded after the first time.

If you use M2Eclipse, then the standard Eclipse compiler will be extended with Maven builders, so you can use all Eclipse compile features.

Comment: you may should first convert your project to maven project,then enjoy the maven dependencies.